# How does the "Revive at Corpse" option work?

Tags: diablo-iii

With the new patch 2.0, Diablo 3 introduced multiple ways to revive once you've been killed. One of the options is "revive at corpse". When I've been on this screen, I've noticed that after I've done it a couple of times, I get a message that says I have a limited number of times left to select this option. When I run out of them, my only choices are to revive in town or at my last check point. I'm wondering if the number of corpse revivals is limited per game or if it's on a timer. If it is per game, how many do I get before I run out? And if they renew on a timer, how much time needs to pass before I get more?

Comment: if you read the patch notes on the battle.net launcher, it says that you can only resurrect at body three times in a row. Have you tried to resurrect using another method after you hit the limit in order to reset the limit?

Comment: i'll do some testing and update my answer in the other question